# Trouble with incoming file

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

My app handles a documents and I open files through "Open in" menu.  When app in a background, everything is OK. But when app not launched, file not opens. URL which incoming at the

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
                                      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication             
                                             annotation:(id)annotation
```

is not `nil`, but the file at this path not exists, Documents/Inbox directory is empty. I can't understand my mistake.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
 {
    if ([url isFileURL]) 
    {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url.path]) {
            NSLog(@"File not exists!");
        }
        if([SUPPORTED_FORMATS containsObject:[[url lastPathComponent] pathExtension]])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url.path forKey:OPENED_FILE];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FILE_IS_OPENED object:url.path];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. When

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method launched, Inbox directory is not empty and there is file that I try to open. I'm just check it, and if Inbox not empty I move the file to destination folder and write new file path to User Defaults.